# Why does Git use the SHA1 of the *compressed* objects rather than the SHA1 of the original objects?

Tags: git, hash, compression, blob, sha1

I'm just curious as to why this choice was made - it basically rules out changing the compression algorithm used by Git - because it doesn't use the SHA1 of the raw blobs. Perhaps there is some efficiency consideration here. Maybe ZLIB is faster at compressing a file than the SHA1 algorithm is at creating the hash, so therefore compressing before hashing is faster?

Here is a link to the original Git README by Linus:

- [root/README](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=README;h=27577f76849c09d3405397244eb3d8ae1d11b0f3;hb=e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290)

And here is the relevant paragraph:

> "There are several kinds of objects in the content-addressable
> collection database.  They are all in deflated with zlib, and start
> off with a tag of their type, and size information about the data.
> The SHA1 hash is always the hash of the *compressed* object, not the
> original one."

Comment: Did you consider that it actually may *allow* you to change the algorithm? After all, if you use the sha1-sum of the raw blob, then something compressed with zlib and the *same* object compressed with bzip2 would have the same sha1 (a collision) which is just plain wrong. I'm not saying this is likely, but it does actually allow for the possibility of multiple compression schemes.

Comment: It's not plain wrong at all - the compression is just for efficient storage and transmission (one would think). The *content* is what's important - regardless of compression mechanism the SHA1 of the raw content would remain the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like you said, it is the *original* README, when Git was started. Since then, it has been changed so that the SHA1 is computed before compressing.

> It’s worth noting that the SHA-1 hash that is used to name the object
>   is the hash of the original data plus this header, so 'sha1sum' file
>   does not match the object name for file. (**Historical note: in the dawn
>   of the age of git the hash was the SHA-1 of the compressed object.**)

http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#object-details

Comment: Thanks - I was under the impression that the internal representation of commits and blobs had not changed since the beginning. Great answer!